# UnsupportedOperationException: Use StringFactory instead

Tags: java, android

I have started getting this crash on Samsung devices os 7.0 in last few days.
when ever some api tries to create a new string it throws an exception saying

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use StringFactory instead.
       at java.lang.String.(String.java:176)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serializedName(CustomClassMapper.java:807)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.propertyName(CustomClassMapper.java:775)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:461)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:317)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:418)
```

or

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use StringFactory instead.
       at java.lang.String.(String.java:201)
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1001)
       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:787)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:922)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:836)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:808)
```

If any body can point to what could be causing this, will a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-developer-preview/issues/2073 says it was a bug in a preview build. But this bug is from 2015. Perhaps the issue regressed on a recent preview  build. This would break every single app - I don't know if you can do anything about it apart from telling the user to use an OS that isn't broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android SDK java lang, it is forbidden to create string use constructor, like `new String("dd")`, it encourages use `StringFactoy`.

```
public String(String original) {
        // Android-changed: Constructor unsupported as all calls are 
        //intercepted by the runtime.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use StringFactory instead.");
    }
```

instead, we should use the StringFactory which is provided by Android SDK.

```
StringFactory.newStringFromString("abc")
```

actually, it calls a native method in the end.

```
@FastNative
public static native String newStringFromString(String toCopy);
```

but the StringFactory is be hidden. so we can not use it anymore.

we should use the default way to create it to avoid creating many string objects

```
String a = "some content"
```

Comment: Ok, and what is StringFactory and how to use it?

Comment: @SolderingIronMen, it is in android SDK. for example to create a string, StringFactory.newStringFromString("abc")

Comment: Lenoarod, the fact is that this class was not found in the Android SDK. I use targetSdkVersion 30.

Comment: @SolderingIronMen I see the android SDK version 30, it is added hide annotation. you can directly use `String a = "abc"`

Comment: Lenoarod, But what if I need to create a string from a byte array with ASCII characters?

Comment: @SolderingIronMen, you can use StringBuffer or  StringBuilder. but you have convert byte to char array.